Why does one call of this function use NRVO while another call of the same function does not?
vector is a struct with two public members X and Y; a parameterized constructor that prints integer constructor called; a copy constructor that prints copy constructor called; and a move constructor that prints move constructor called      <== This line is different\n.
The function makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero() returns the vector {5, 5} if arg is 0. otherwise it returns {2, 2}.
The main function constructs vector A using makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero(1) and constructs vector B using makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero(0).
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>

struct vector{
    int X, Y;
    vector(int X, int Y) : X(X), Y(Y){
        printf("integer constructor called\n");
    }
    vector(const vector& other): X(other.X), Y(other.Y){
        printf("copy constructor called\n");
    }
    vector(vector&& other): X(other.X), Y(other.Y){
        printf("move constructor called      <== This line is different\n\n");
    }
};

vector makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero(bool Arg){
    if(Arg){
        vector A(0, 0);
        A.X = 5;
        A.Y = 5;
        return A;
    }
    else {
        vector B(1,1);
        B.X = 2;
        B.Y = 2;
        return B;
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Making Vector\n");
    vector A = makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero(1);
    printf("Made Vector\n");
    printf("Making Another Vector\n");
    vector B = makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero(0);
    printf("Made Vector\n");
}

The output of this code is:
Making Vector
integer constructor called
Made Vector
Making Another Vector
integer constructor called
move constructor called      <== This line is different
Made Vector


However, I expected the following output, because of NRVO:
Making Vector
integer constructor called
Made Vector
Making Another Vector
integer constructor called
Made Vector

Why is the local variable B of makeVectorx5y5IfNotZero() being moved into the local variable B of main(), rather than just constructing a single variable at the same memory address?
Compiler version (output of g++ --version):
g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


please inform me whether the explanation of the code at the beginning is verbose, and if i should include my debugging test using gdb command line debugging tool

g++ --version should be shown.

implementing change now

It is a gcc limitation (it doesn't optimize the branch), which Jason just happened to touch upon a few weeks ago. Watch C++ Weekly - Ep 456 - RVO + Trivial Types = Faster Code.

watching this video now

@PepijnKramer I have watched the video, and it has answered my question. My main takeaway is, as you said, its a gcc limitation. So do I just delete this stack overflow post, or just leave it here, untill someone answers? Or is there a way to close this post?

You can write up an answer to your own question, and then (after the waiting time) accept it as an answer.

ok, doing that now.

fyi, you can get all compilers to still do NRVO if you wrap it in a lamda godbolt example, and no compiler emits any code for the lambda itself.

ok, I shall change the printf

Sure, I shall give it a try

Quoting @PepijnKramer in the comments

It is a gcc limitation (it doesn't optimize the branch)

This discussed more in detail in this video C++ Weekly - Ep 456 - RVO + Trivial Types = Faster Code
